# Configuring PHP MySql extension

Tags: mysql, php, apache-2.4

I am trying to load a MySql extension for PHP development.

Running `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` I can see that the MySql extension is not loaded. This is also apparent when running a script that uses the `mysql_connect` function and receiving the error `Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\Apache24\htdocs\test.php on line 11`.

Running `php --ini` I receive an output of:

```
Loaded Configuration File:          C:\php\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in:  (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:       (none)
```

So when I edit my php.ini file in order to enable the MySql extension I know I am editing the correct .ini file. The output of `phpinfo()` points to the same file.

In my php.ini file I have changed

```
;extension=php_mysql.dll
```

to

```
 extension=php_mysql.dll
```

For my extension directory in my php.ini file:

```
extension_dir = "./ext"
```

within that directory I do have the `php_mysql.dll` file.

I am at a bit of a loss here and don't really know what I am missing. Every answer I have found on the SE sites and elsewhere just point to uncommenting a line in the php.ini file and checking that the extension_dir is pointing to a location that contains the correct .dll file.

What am I missing to properly load this extension?

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A common cause of this can be php's install directory not being included in the `PATH` environment variable ( See: *[PHP: Installation of Extensions in Windows](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.extensions.php)* ), which causes the php module to fail to find mysql.

Any error in the logs about failure to load the extension?